What is the equivalent of Artin gluing for quasicoherent sheaves?
Given a topological space or locale $X$ and an open $j : U \hookrightarrow X$ with closed complement $i : K \hookrightarrow X$, the inverse image functor $\langle i^*, j^* \rangle : \textbf{Sh} (X) \to \textbf{Sh} (K) \times \textbf{Sh} (U)$ is conservative, preserves equalisers, and has a right adjoint, hence is comonadic.
After some calculation, one obtains that the category of coalgebras of the comonad can be described more simply as the comma category $(\textbf{Sh} (K) \downarrow i^* j_*)$: thus, $\textbf{Sh} (X)$ is equivalent to the category whose objects are tuples $(W, V, f)$ where $W$ is sheaf on $K$, $V$ is a sheaf on $U$, and $f : W \to i^* j_* V$ is a morphism of sheaves on $K$.
Artin gluing is a generalisation of the above, taking as input two toposes and a functor between them preserving finite limits and yielding a new topos containing one as an open subtopos and the other as a closed subtopos.
(In fact, the construction is the same: just form the comma category of the given functor!)
Question.
Is there an analogue of Artin gluing, replacing spaces with schemes, toposes with abelian categories, and sheaves of sets with quasicoherent sheaves of modules?

Even for the simplest case of a closed point of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ things seem much more complicated.
The functor $\textbf{Mod} (\mathbb{Z}) \to \textbf{Mod} (\mathbb{F}_p) \times \textbf{Mod} (\mathbb{Z} [p^{-1}])$ sending $M$ to the pair $(M \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{F}_p, M \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z} [p^{-1}])$ is not even conservative: the obvious epimorphism $\mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ ($n \ge 1$) becomes an isomorphism after tensoring with either $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Z} [p^{-1}]$, but is not itself an isomorphism for $n > 1$.
Put another way, decomposing $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z} [p^{-1}]$ loses information about $p^n$-torsion for $n > 1$.
The obvious fix is to replace $\mathbb{F}_p$ with the local ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.
Then, by flat descent, or just computing by hand, we have the following bipullback square:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\textbf{Mod} (\mathbb{Z}) @>>> \textbf{Mod} (\mathbb{Z} [p^{-1}]) \\
@VVV \cong @VVV \\
\textbf{Mod} (\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}) @>>> \textbf{Mod} (\mathbb{Q})
\end{CD}$$
But this feels qualitatively different from Artin gluing: it is symmetric in the inputs (and seems to require a third category).
This is surely related to the fact that $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z} [p^{-1}]$ and $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ are not disjoint.
On the other hand, the Artin gluing construction does make sense: given abelian categories $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ and a left exact functor $F : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$, the comma category $\mathcal{C} = (\mathcal{B} \downarrow F)$ is also an abelian category.
Putting $\mathcal{A} = \textbf{Mod} (\mathbb{Z} [p^{-1}])$ and $\mathcal{B} = \textbf{Mod} (\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})$ and $F (M) = M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z} [p^{-1}]} \mathbb{Q}$, we do get $\textbf{Mod} (\mathbb{Z})$ as a full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$, namely the one whose objects are $(N, M, f)$ such that $f : N \to F (M)$ is universal with respect to $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-homomorphisms from $N$ to a $\mathbb{Q}$-module.
Where does this extra condition come from, and what does $\mathcal{C}$ itself correspond to – is it the category of quasicoherent sheaves on some scheme?

A good analog is to consider the formal completion (so $\mathbb{Z}_p$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_p$ in your example). See Artin "Algebraization of Formal Moduli: II. Existence of Modifications", Theorem 2.6 for the noetherian affine case, Beauville–Laszlo for the non-affine case with vector bundles, and Ben Bassat–Temkin for a global case.

P.S. This works only for quasi-coherent sheaves. For example, the module $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}p$ becomes zero after tensoring by $\mathbb{Q}{p}$ and has zero completion.

Artin gluing works without change but the ugly sheaf of rings $i^{-1} \mathcal{O}_X$ appears. The structure sheaf of the formal completion can be understood as an approximation to this sheaf (which however does the job only for coherent sheaves). According to Fujiwara-Kato, one can build an analog with henselizations or Zariski localization taking the role of formal completions, but I haven't worked with those.
